# setting a max width in Captivate 9

Tags: javascript, css, adobe-captivate

I am looking for a way to set a max width on a captivate quiz slideshow that implements scaling. I have done some research and come across some answers for much older versions such as this for captivate 6:
https://forums.adobe.com/message/6019502#6019502

```
var isMobile;

    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )
    {
      isMobile = true;
    }
    else
    {
      isMobile = false;
    }



 Then in the CPM.js find:
    cp.shouldScale = cp.D.project.shc;
    and replace with:

    if(isMobile)
    {
       cp.shouldScale = cp.D.project.shc;
    }
      else
    {
       cp.shouldScale = false;
    }
```

The issue seems to be that it is not recognizing the scale up as intended. My question is, is there a known way to create a stop point where the captivate scaling will stop going up?

Update: creating a responsive project is cost prohibitive, as it would require rebuilding the entire project of 180+ slides for each view mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When generating a new captivate 9 project, we found that there is, in the pre-production settings, a checkbox that you can set scalability with. This scalability will expand all the way up and down, which means it does not operate necessarily on mobile first design principle, and on larger screens does cause blurring.